# Android preview processing while video recording

Tags: android, video-capture

I am using Android development (SDK 2.2) and I would like to make a video recording with `mediaRecorder` and, at the same time, do some process on each preview frame.

I record video with `MediaRecorder` in a project, in an other I use the `onPreviewFrame(byte[] data`, `Camera camera`) (from `PreviewCallback`) for processing preview pictures.

I've tried to create a Camera and use it with `mediaRecorder` (`setCamera` function) but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to do both in the same time?

Actually I don't understand how to link two things?

My code :

```
package ch.fraise;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,
    Camera.AutoFocusCallback {

private SurfaceView preview;
private SurfaceHolder previewHolder;

private MediaRecorder mRecorder;
private Camera mCamera;
private boolean mPreviewRunning = false;
private boolean mCaptureFrame = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e("", "Begin onCreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
    previewHolder = preview.getHolder();
    previewHolder.addCallback(this);
    previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.capture_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public void startRecording() {
    Log.e("", "Begin StartRecording");
    mCaptureFrame = true;
    mRecorder.start();
}

public void stopRecording() {
    Log.e("", "Begin StopChange");
    mRecorder.stop();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.startRecording:
        startRecording();
        return true;
    case R.id.stopRecording:
        stopRecording();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.e("", "Begin surfaceDestroy");
    mCamera = Camera.open();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mPreviewRunning = false;
    mCamera.release();

    mRecorder.reset();
    mRecorder.release();
}

@Override
public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/*
 * PreviewCallback()
 * 
 * this callback captures the preview at every frame and puts it in a byte
 * buffer. we will evaluate if this is a frame that we want to process, and
 * if so, we will send it to an asynchronous thread that will process it to
 * an ARGB Bitmap and POST it to the server
 */
PreviewCallback previewCallback = new PreviewCallback() {
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.e("", "onPreviewFrame pass");
        if (mCaptureFrame) {
            mCaptureFrame = false;
            // new FrameHandler().execute(data);
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    Log.e("", "Begin SurfaceChange");

    mRecorder.reset();
    mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/videotest2.mp4");
    mRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);

    mRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder.getSurface());
    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (mPreviewRunning)
        mCamera.stopPreview();

    Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
    // p.setPreviewSize(width, height);
    mCamera.setParameters(p);

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCallback);

    mCamera.startPreview();
    mPreviewRunning = true;

}

}
```

and the permissions in the XML file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: i've added my code but i have the following error W/System.err( 5476): java.io.IOException: prepare failed. the application run after this first error, until i start video recording. Then i have a java.lang.IllegalStateException
E/AndroidRuntime( 5476): at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)

Comment: Hi, Are you able to achieve this? I am also stuck at this point.

Comment: Hi, I'm also stuck due to this issue, have you found solution?

Answer (score 6):

Eureka! The trick is to attach your `PreviewCallback` in the `surfaceChanged(...)` `SurfaceHolder.Callback`! After doing this, you'll continue to get preview frame data after a MediaRecorder is running!

For example:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] _data, Camera _camera) {
                Log.d("onPreviewFrame-surfaceChanged",String.format("Got %d bytes of camera data", _data.length));
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: I do it like above, but still can't get preview frame data after a MediaRecorder is running! It really work for you ?

Comment: Yeah, I was using Android 4.2 at that time. Make sure you attach the SufaceHolder.Callback before starting MediaRecorder. Post your source and I'll take a look.

Comment: @dbro, no. Your trick doesn't work. If I call `mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera)` method, then I must call `mCamera.unlock()` before what doesn't let getting preview frames. If I don't call `mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera)` method, `mMediaRecorder.start()` crashes with `IllegalStateException` because camera is already in use. Can you post more (or full) code how did you did your eureka trick?

Answer (score 4):

you cannot access the video stream while recording, onPreviewFrame will not get called once you start recording. Oddly, onPreviewFrame does not seem to get called after you record either...

Comment: That's wrong. You simply need to start listening again after recording.

Answer (score 0):

You just add  tag to your manifest file .Thus it will work.Sample code shown below.

eg:-

```
   </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    ***<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />***
</manifest>
```

Comment: Hi nikhilkilivayil! Thanks for your help! Unfortunately i've added the line <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" /> but it seems it is not working either. I've seen when the recording start, the onFramePreview stop to be called! Maybe they can run together!?

Comment: I have this problem also. May be we can try to decode the video meanwhile to get raw image real time?

Comment: @ nikhilkilivayil : what solution do u got? How you got camera preview in real time while recording using mediarecorder ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using os 2.2 or higher then use this method your prepare failed and other exception will removed

```
 public boolean startRecording() {
    try {
        camera.unlock();

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
                .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

        File tempFile = new File(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
                .toString());

        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(tempFile.getPath());
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(videoFramesPerSecond);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(surfaceView.getWidth(),
                surfaceView.getHeight());
        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(maxFileSizeInBytes);
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        mediaRecorder.start();

        return true;
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```