# How to capture / grab frames from the video stream?

Tags: android, video-streaming, packet-capture

In my case, the video stream is from Android MediaRecorder. [Update] From some online information, the video stream normally can be fed in fd in the function setOutputFile(FileDescriptor fd).

A post related to capture frames is here:
"[Processing Android video frame by frame while recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839109/processing-android-video-frame-by-frame-while-recording?rq=1)"

One answer is:

> 1. Open a stream using the NDK (possibly api, depending on implementations)
> 2. Modify the bytes of the stream - each frame is sent as a separate packet. You have to grab each packet from the camera, and modify it.
>      You can do a replace of colors, or you can translate. You can also use
>      OpenGL to modify the image entirely by adding things like glass
>      effects.
> 3. ...

But I do not know what API/libraries can be used to capture/grab each frame from the video stream.
(I have been able to encode frames to a video file using ffmpeg)

I read "[wiki: Streaming media with ffserver](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Streaming%20media%20with%20ffserver)"

But I am not clear about how to make programs in C/c++ to capture/grab frames from the video stream.

Links with examples and tutorials would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably used the FFmpeg command line tool for encoding frames to a video. Now it's time to use the libraries FFmpeg uses: libavcodec, libavformat, libavutil ect. Just download a source from [the FFmpeg download page](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) and you will find some examples how to use them in the `doc/examples/` directory. One great example is the [decoding and encoding](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/decoding__encoding_8c_source.html) example.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I used FFmpeg libraries to decode a video file, and process each frame, and then encode to another video file. It works. Right now, I will change the input video file to an input video stream. But the examples in ffmpeg do not touch this topic.

Comment: Your question is not clear then. Please provide more information about what you want. Like what stream do you want to provide? Some of them are RTP, RTMP or MPEGTS. The [Streamingguide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/StreamingGuide) can maybe help you choose.

Comment: In my post, it writes: "In my case, the video stream is from Android MediaRecorder.". I think you might not touch on the topic before. I read related tutorials in ffmpeg documents. But the problem is no api examples exist. I do not know what API/libraries can be used to capture/grab each frame from the video stream. But thank you anyway.