# How to show a preview frame while using MediaRecorder

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I want to use media recorder to record a video. Meanwhile, I need process the preview frame in real time.

I read many articles about this. It seems that while recording, no preview frame is possible.

Is this true? Does anyone know how to get the preview frame to show up while recording?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `onPreviewFrame` callback function of `PreviewCallback`. Kindly refer [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html) for details.

Following SO question will also help you:

[android-preview-processing-while-video-recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386903/android-preview-processing-while-video-recording)